# Unexpected behaviour when combining string columns with nan values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

With the following df

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Peter','Karl'], 'B':[np.nan,'Jackson']})
```

I want a column AddCols that combines the column A and B, sometimes they could be numbers, but even if so I want to handle with them as strings so I cast:

```
data['AddCols'] = data['A'].astype('string') +','+ data['B'].astype('string')
```

But the result, whenever A or B is NAN returns a NAN:

```
'|    | AddCols      |
 |---:|:-------------|
 |  0 | <NA>         |
 |  1 | Karl,Jackson |'
```

Using astype(str) creates a literal string nan, that's why I am using astype('string').

Why is this happening and how to solve it? Ideally for the first row (idx 0) I would want simply:

```
Peter,
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is replace NaN to emty strings, because if use `+` operator with strings `NaN` is not excluded, so `np.nan + 'any string' = np.nan`:

```
data['AddCols'] = (data['A'].fillna('').astype('string') +','+ 
                   data['B'].fillna('').astype('string'))
```

Or `nae_rep` in [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
data['AddCols'] = (data['A'].astype('string')
                            .str.cat(data['B'].fillna('').astype('string'), 
                                     na_rep='', sep=','))

print (data)
       A        B       AddCols
0  Peter      NaN        Peter,
1   Karl  Jackson  Karl,Jackson
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but why the code is behaving like that?

Comment: @AlejandroA - because by defult if add `NaN` to anything string get `NaN`, if add `NaN` to number outpu tis number.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation, your code is behaving as expected. if you dont give a presentation of NaN alias `na_rep`, and there is a `NaN`, missing values in the Series/Index are omitted from the result. That is, the result of concatenating a `string` to a `NaN` is `NaN`

```
data['AddCols'] = data['A'].astype('string') +','+ data['B'].fillna('').astype(str)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but why the code is behaving like that?

Comment: See my edits for explanation